# How can i get the route distance without the ferry km in HERE API

Tags: here-api

I would like to get the route distance with ferry km excluded.

Currently i am using the following request :

```
https://tce.cit.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?
mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&
truckType=tractorTruck&
maneuverAttributes=none&
combineChange=true&
routeAttributes=none,wp,sm,sh,no&
linkAttributes=none&
legAttributes=none&
detail=1&
alternatives=2&
rollup=total,country&
jsonattributes=41&
waypoint0=geo!stopOver!51.006511,2.321095&
waypoint1=geo!stopOver!51.137062,0.911495
```

This request gives 128.81 km but without ferry the distance is under 100 km.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straight attribute or field which provides you this value. However, you can get this by using the below query where link information is provided.Every link has flags. You can search for the flag of your interest (in your case railFerry) and sum their lengths.This will give you the ferry length in your route distance.

```
https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=geo!stopOver!51.006511,2.321095&waypoint1=geo!stopOver!51.137062,0.911495&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Aenabled&app_id=xxx&app_code=yyy&representation=linkPaging&language=de-de&returnElevation=true&maneuverAttributes=position%2Clength%2CtravelTime%2CstartAngle&instructionFormat=text&routeAttributes=waypoints%2Csummary
```